# VSCode files.associations

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some `.txt` files in a subfolder of my project which contain `SQL` code. I want `SQL` syntax highlighting so I added this to my <del>workspace</del> folder settings:

```json
{
    "files.associations": {
        "**/somefolder/*.txt": "sql" 
    }
}
```

This works when there are the two stars in front of the folder name. But `somefolder` actually is a folder direct under my project's root.

Why can I not write the glob like `somefolder/**/*.txt`?

Answer (score 27):

Seems like this new version of VSCode requires you to use the `**` at the start regardless:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "**/somefolder/**/*.txt": "sql" 
    }
}
```

That should work

Comment: Could you explain this `**`? Why do I need it in the beginning? I understand it in the middle to do a recursive matching, but what about the beginning?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin my posted answer explains this, you can check

Answer (score 7):

**Context:** Trying to answer the additional bounty question by [@gremo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220180/gremo):

#### TL;DR

This is due to `full path` vs `filename` matching behavior based on presence of `/`. The same is obscurely mentioned in `VSCode` docs as well. Read on for details.

#### Details:

As requested by [@gremo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220180/gremo), quoting from following reputable source:

[Language Support in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_can-i-map-additional-file-extensions-to-a-language)

> Note that the pattern is a glob pattern that will match on the full
> path of the file if it contains a / and will match on the file name
> otherwise.

Read closely and you'll see the word `full path of the file` and `file name` stand out!

i.e. from above we can infer that depending on existence of `/` it will decide match mode/behavior of `full path match` vs `partial/filename match`!

This further makes more sense when we see that `relative` paths are not yet allowed, as mentioned at [issue #12805 Allow workspace relative files.associations setting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12805) posted by [@Bob_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4944425/bob) in his answer.

###### Hopefully above sheds light on:

1. Why pattern `somefolder/*.txt` doesn't match?

   - since there is a `/` in pattern, this will do a `full path` matching
   - in our case full path of loaded files will be: `c:\scratch\VsCodePatternTest\somefolder\foo.txt` and `c:\scratch\VsCodePatternTest\foo.txt`
   - so we're essentially trying to match above `full path` to pattern: `somefolder/*.txt`
   - **Result**: Neither matched!
   - **Note**:   Technically this path will NEVER match anything, since on `Windows/Linux/Mac` u can't have an absolute path like above..
     it needs to be rooted somehow:

     ```
             E.g. on Windows:
                c:/somefolder  (or use `\\` for back slashes on windows)
             on Linux/Mac:
                /somefolder
     ```
2. Why pattern `**/somefolder/*.txt` match?

   - now again since there is a `/` in pattern, this will do a `full path` matching
   - like above again the full path of loaded files will be: `c:\scratch\VsCodePatternTest\somefolder\foo.txt` and `c:\scratch\VsCodePatternTest\foo.txt`
   - so we're essentially trying to match above `full path` to pattern: `**/somefolder/*.txt`
   - **Result**: Only one file match!
3. Bonus: Why pattern `foo.txt` match?

   - now this time since there is **NO** `/` in pattern, this will do `filename` matching
   - like above again the full path of loaded files will be: `c:\scratch\VsCodePatternTest\somefolder\foo.txt` and `c:\scratch\VsCodePatternTest\foo.txt`
   - so we're essentially trying to match above `filename` i.e. `foo.txt` and `foo.txt` to pattern: `foo.txt`
   - **Result**: Both files match!

###### Tested above cases with:

- Version/OS:

  ```
    VSCode 1.78.1 on Windows 10 x64
  ```
- Project/Workspace structure:

  ```
    c:\scratch\VsCodePatternTest
        \.vscode
            settings.json
        \foo.txt
        \somefolder
            \foo.txt
  ```

Hope this clears things up!

Comment: Thanks but for completeness, why can't I use a token like ${workspaceRoot} in workspace settings? e.g. `"${workspaceRoot}/scripts/*.txt"`

Comment: @StevenLiekens I am not sure yet, but did u try this with other variables like: ${workspaceRoot} etc?

Answer (score 3):

For a jekyll site the following workspace setting works for me

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.html": "jekyll",
        "**/_site/**/*.html": "html",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems related to [issue #12805 Allow workspace relative files.associations setting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12805), where, in some comments, user bpasero (a staff member) states:

> Since it is totally valid to open files without having a workspace open we cannot allow workspace relative paths here.
>
> [...] allowing workspace relative paths is causing many issues because they do not work once you have no workspace open.
>
> [...] For one a user might not easily understand the difference between workspace and global association setting, it is too subtle. And then while we could support `${workspaceRoot}` it would not work when no workspace is open and again I fear this is too subtle...