# VSCode: how to disable static analysis for specific files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, static-analysis

I have some badly formatted html files that I use as input for my unit tests. I need them to be badly formatted for my test. How do I exclude them from static analysis in VSCode?

I'd like to continue using static analysis for all other files. It really bothers me have a non empty Problems tab in my project.

Comment: I really wish there was an answer to this! I have some C++ code I am translating into another language, and I'm keeping the C++ files around only for review. Yet, VS Code keeps trying to find errors in it, and "jumping to problems" takes me to "errors" (all due to me only importing a subset of the source files) in the C++ files when trying to navigate errors elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

You can change the [`files.associations` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_can-i-map-additional-file-extensions-to-a-language) in your `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
    "files.associations": {
        "**/foobar/*.html": "ignore",
    },
}
```

That way, vscode will not treat these files as HTML.

Note that the globs for this setting are  [quite finnicky](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12805),
so unfortunately you can't use e.g. `${workspaceFolder}`, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805677/vscode-files-associations).

Depending on what plugins you use for static analysis, you might be able to use "xml" or something like that instead of "ignore" to get at least some syntax highlighting for those files if that matters to you.