# In VS Code, how can I force the language mode based on a special comment in the file content?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I would like to force some files to be of a specific type, regardless of their extensions.

I am thinking about a comment to put on top that would say: Hey, I am a plain text (example).

Any idea?

Comment: are the kinds of file type associations you want to make able to be based upon the file extensions? Or do the file extensions not have a clear, usable pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VSCode settings, you can associate the files you want with a specific language:

```json
"settings": {
        "files.associations": {
            "toto.py": "markdown"
        }
}
```

It is just like adding the plain text on top of each file, you have also a non-automatic action, but it leaves your files cleaner.

[EDIT] Following the comment from @starball, you can find more detailed answers on similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973619/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-with-a-certain-language-in-vs-code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805677/vscode-files-associations) for example (the second one might be interesting if you put your copied files in a single place!).

Comment: if this is your answer, you should probably be flagging as a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973619/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-with-a-certain-language-in-vs-code instead of answer-posting. see [answer]. that said, I think this question should provide more details before getting answers.

Comment: This is a possible solution. But when copying files, I would need to reconfigure vscode. any other idea?